# Does Google Maps provide the ability to draw multiple polygons on a map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, draw, polygon

Using the Google Maps JavaScript v3 API, is it possible to draw multiple separate polygons on the same map? And include a message box that appears after drawing each shape with an alert: 'Click rest to draw another'?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are able to draw multiple polygons on the Map; check out the [Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools). If you want to display a message after completing one shape, you will want to define a listener function against the `DrawingManager` that listens for one of several possible completion event notifications:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingMgr, 'overlaycomplete', function( event ){
    var shape = event.overlay;
    var path = shape.getPath();    //returns an MVCArray of LatLng instances
    for ( var i = 0; i < path.length; i++ ) {
        var lat = path.getAt(i).lat(); //Corrected as per MVCArray
        var lng = path.getAt(i).lng(); //Corrected as per MVCArray
        //do something with the data...
    }
    //put your message display code here
});
```

Within the function callback, you have access to the shape that was just completed. So in the code above, `event.overlay` will provide you with a direct reference to the shape. If we assume that the shape is a `Polygon`, you would then be able to access the shape's members directly, as shown above. The full set of `Polygon` members is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).

Comment: Thank you:) That helps me. how Can I get the data related to the shape  created in the event listener that you mentioned .. Thanx

Comment: I've updated the code within the callback function above to show you how you can get a reference to the shape that was created and then begin pulling out its associated data. And a link to the docs for `Polygon`, so you can go deeper.

Comment: Thank you, but that returns an exception , I changed the two lines inside the FOR loop and I used "path.getAt(i)" instead of path[i] and that worked... Thank you for help

Comment: Nice. I forgot about that MVCArray thing - and now you are helping me. Glad to help -

Answer (score 0):

I put the whole code as worked for me :

```
enter code here
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingMgr, 'overlaycomplete', function( event ){
var shape = event.overlay;
var path = shape.getPath();    //returns an Array of LatLng
for ( var i = 0; i < path.length; i++ ) {
    var lat = path.getAt(i).lat();
    var lng = path.getAt(i).lng();
    //do something with the data...
}
//put your message display code here
```

});